# What's the Status of CiviVolunteer 2.0's Compatibility with CiviCRM 4.7 on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, civivolunteer

I'm looking for an update on the status of CiviVolunteer 2.0 compatibility in WordPress with the latest version of CiviCRM. I'm developing a volunteer intake process and we've been stalling hoping to take advantage of the new features found in CiviVolunteer 2.0. I'm running CiviCRM 4.7.6 and an older version of CiviVolunteer (version 4.5-1.4.1) because CiviVolunteer 2.0 is not considered compatible with 4.7 and above. My understanding was that there was a blocking issue that was preventing full compatibility, but I also seem to recall hearing that you could try your luck using CiviVolunteer 2.0 and CiviCRM 4.7 together by changing the version strings before installing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've done a fair amount of testing of CiviVolunteer 2.x on 4.7. We found a handful of issues including a core bug. The outstanding Volunteer issue that keeps CiviVolunteer from being compatible with 4.7 is: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/VOL-196

The core bug we found was patched and the PR included in the CiviCRM 4.7.5 release. So you should be good on that score.

Just for completeness and/or if others make their way here via google in the future, the 4.7.5 release contained a regression that broke the Manage Groups screen.
So CiviVolunteer will support 4.7.6+ pursuant to the resolution of the linked issue as well as the currently published 4.6.x branch.

I have not found any Wordpress specific bugs in my testing which has been split fairly evenly between Drupal and Wordpress installs.

Comment: Thanks Toby and Dan. Will we soon be able to install CiviVolunteer from within the extension manager in WP? It doesn't show as compatible with my version yet - CiviCRM 4.7.6.

Comment: Incidentally, the Angular Profiles extension wasn't flagged as compatible with 4.7. We did this yesterday, so if you're had the "Prerequisite check failed" error, you can install Angular Profiles now.

Answer (score 3):

Most of the issues blocking CiviVolunteer 2.0 working with 4.7 are resolved. I believe there were one or two still outstanding, though. I'm going to check with one of my colleagues here at Ginkgo Street Labs and we'll post an answer shortly.